# Softlayer API - How to create an instance with firewall rules?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In AWS I create an instance with a predefined security group. What is the equivalent way to create an instance in SoftLayer?

I am using Python Client API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These could be the equivalent solutions:

1. You can order an instance with hardware firewall and configure the
   rules for it, for the next instance you can **share the rules between
   firewalls**.
2. **Order a firewall dedicated to the public
   vlan**, so it will apply all the rules for the instances which reside
   in this vlan.
3. **Vyatta gateways**, but you should have the enough
   technical knowledge to configure this

Comment: You again coming to my rescue :-)

Comment: So, I need to create a public vlan first. Right?

Comment: Yep, that's right. First, you need to order the vlan and then you will be able to add firewall

Comment: Let me know if you need any assistance with it

Comment: Ruber, Are you IBMer?

Comment: I'm SoftLayer'er :)

Comment: There seem to be a new option in SoftLayer now, Security_Groups